# Remove duplicate coordinates from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an array of coordinates which are strings. So one string is a coordinate with the lat and long separated by a comma.

For example: `47.551170,18.961630`

So my array looks like this:

```
 47.551090,18.961610
 47.551010,18.961600
 47.550910,18.961600
 47.550830,18.961610
 47.550750,18.961640
 47.550690,18.961680
 47.549980,18.962870
 47.549170,18.964170
 47.548950,18.964500
 47.548840,18.964620
 47.548710,18.964690
 47.548470,18.964690
 47.548400,18.964690
 47.547990,18.964720
```

How can I delete a coordinate if either it's lat or long matches another coordinate's lat or long in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *Array1 = @[@"47.551090,18.961610",
                           @"47.551010,18.961600",
                           @"47.550910,18.961600",
                           @"47.550830,18.961610",
                           @"47.550750,18.961640",
                           @"47.550690,18.961680",
                           @"47.549980,18.962870",
                           @"47.549170,18.964170",
                           @"47.548950,18.964500",
                           @"47.548840,18.964620",
                           @"47.548710,18.964690",
                           @"47.548470,18.964690",
                           @"47.548400,18.964690",
                           @"47.547990,18.964720"];

NSMutableArray *finalArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *str in Array1) {
    NSArray *temp=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    if(temp!=nil && [temp count]==2){
        BOOL isSame=NO;
        for(NSString *s in finalArr){
             NSArray *temp2=[s componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
            if([[temp objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:[temp2 objectAtIndex:0]]){
                isSame=YES;
                break;
            }

            if([[temp objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:[temp2 objectAtIndex:1]]){
                isSame=YES;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(isSame==NO){
            [finalArr addObject:str];
        }
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",finalArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this using `NSMutableSet`:-

```
NSMutableArray *Array1 = @[@"47.551090,18.961610",
@"47.551010,18.961600",
@"47.550910,18.961600",
@"47.550830,18.961610",
@"47.550750,18.961640",
@"47.550690,18.961680",
@"47.549980,18.962870",
@"47.549170,18.964170",
@"47.548950,18.964500",
@"47.548840,18.964620",
@"47.548710,18.964690",
@"47.548470,18.964690",
@"47.548400,18.964690",
@"47.547990,18.964720", nil];

NSMutableSet *uniqueMakes = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:Array1];
```

Now If you Print The uniqueMakes using `NSLog` Then it print only those which is unique not repeated after this u can show these values on the `MapView`.

If you want to study more about NSSet then go to this link http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsset .

Comment: The problem with NSSet is that the coordinates should remain in the same order, NSSet is unordered unfortunately.

Comment: You can sort nsset objects using this [mySet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]; , NSSortDescriptor is descriptors

Comment: @BalázsVincze How about NSOrderedSet?

Comment: we can also use NSOrderedSet sorts the data to avoid repeated data

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to convert those strings into `CLLocationCoordinate2D` objects so that you can compare values rather than strings. If you provide an `==` override, then you can use swift's `contains` method to easily create an array of unique coordinates like so:

```
var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
for string in stringArray {
    let coordinateStrings = string.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(coordinateStrings[0])!, longitude: Double(coordinateStrings[1])!)
    coordinates.append(coordinate)
}

func ==(lhs: CLLocationCoordinate2D, rhs: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
    //If you really do mean lat OR long, then change the && to ||
    return lhs.latitude == rhs.latitude && lhs.longitude == rhs.longitude
}

var uniqueCoordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
for coordinate in coordinates {
    if !uniqueCoordinates.contains(coordinate) {
        uniqueCoordinates.append(coordinate)
    }
}
```

Then, if you want to convert those coordinates back into strings, you can do so:

```
var uniqueStrings: [String] = []
for coordinate in uniqueCoordinates {
    let uniqueString = String(format: "%f,%f", coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude)
    uniqueStrings.append(uniqueString)
}
```

Comment: Anyway you could write this in Obj-C? And yes, I do mean lat and long, I know how to comapre two coordiantes to see if they match. What I need to know is how to compare their lat or long values so not a single lat value will match another lat value or long value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple use `NSOrderedSet`, `NSMutableSet` or `NSSet` which is to store distinct values only, it will automatically ignore duplicate values.

> The NSMutableSet class declares the programmatic interface to a mutable, unordered collection of distinct objects.
>
> NSOrderedSet and its subclass, NSMutableOrderedSet, declare the programmatic interfaces to an ordered collection of objects.

Read more in [Apple Documentation about `NSMutableSet`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZ4L38_57MAhUFn5QKHe63DVoQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FReference%2FFoundation%2FClasses%2FNSMutableSet_Class%2F&usg=AFQjCNGUVAyNH3NeHO0XEep-nxYerxHUKw) and [NSOrderedSet Class Reference](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYycHkkJ_MAhUEn5QKHd4VAgkQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fmac%2Fdocumentation%2FFoundation%2FReference%2FNSOrderedSet_Class%2F&usg=AFQjCNF7351-ZZ4pyEKhAiFHrx5FuFfAZg&bvm=bv.119967911,d.dGo)

```
NSOrderedSet *uniqueSet = [NSOrderedSet setWithObjects:@"47.551090,18.961610",
@"47.551010,18.961600",
@"47.550910,18.961600",
@"47.550830,18.961610",
@"47.550750,18.961640",
@"47.550690,18.961680",
@"47.549980,18.962870",
@"47.549170,18.964170",
@"47.548950,18.964500",
@"47.548840,18.964620",
@"47.548710,18.964690",
@"47.548470,18.964690",
@"47.548400,18.964690",
@"47.547990,18.964720", nil];

NSLog(@"Unique List : %@",uniqueSet);
```

Check it by adding any value multiple times it will show only once when you log.

Happy coding :)

Comment: The problem with NSSet is that the coordinates should remain in the same order, NSSet is unordered unfortunately.

Comment: There is also a solution use `NSOrderedSet` which keeps order. Read more about [it in NSOrderedSet Class Reference](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYycHkkJ_MAhUEn5QKHd4VAgkQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fmac%2Fdocumentation%2FFoundation%2FReference%2FNSOrderedSet_Class%2F&usg=AFQjCNF7351-ZZ4pyEKhAiFHrx5FuFfAZg&bvm=bv.119967911,d.dGo)

Comment: That would only help for checking if any of the coordinates have duplicates, but not the lats or longs individually

Comment: @BalázsVincze given answer satisfies all the need of what you asked in question. You need to make changes according to your need, nobody gives you complete code. Question should mention problem clearly, its not written anywhere. Put your efforts you will find solution. This community is to solve problem, not provide whole code. People can only guide you. I hope you understand.

Comment: The question clearly states what I am asking for. Read the last line again